# PHP, MySQL optimizing sorting based on an external sorting faction

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I'm trying to optimize the speed of data processing and would like to have any suggestions for a scalable solution to the following:
I have a PHP array looking like:

```
$arr = array(
           2543 => 1,
           2123 => 2,
           2431 => 1,
           3223 => 3,
           ...
       );
```

Here the keys represent unique item ids and the value, orders of these ids in a system. Using this (very big) array I would like to extract the items assign them their priority and sort in the most efficient manner.
 My current solution is rather straight forward (using PDO and primarily based on PHP):

```
$item_ids = array_keys($arr);
$item_ids_csv = implode(",", $item_ids);

$sql = "SELECT `id`,`name` 
        FROM `item_data`
        WHERE `id` IN ($item_ids_csv);";

#execute is a custom function returning a PDO execution
$items = $this->execute($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($items as &$item){
    $item['order'] = $arr[$item['id']];
}

usort($items, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
});

print_r($items);
```

Which works just fine, but I'm however wondering if the above PHP operation is possible entirely in SQL? Maybe I could `INNER JOIN` the orders `ON` each id and `ORDER BY` these? 
I'm figuring that it wound save me some processing time to shift this logic to the database, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I would have to `ORDER BY` the array values from the `$arr` array.

Comment: Are there only 3 values to 'order'? If so, you could join together three selects.

Comment: Where does the `$arr` come from? Is it in the database as well?

Comment: `$arr` is generated based mined data from a computer learning algorithm and loaded as a CSV file.

Comment: "loaded as a CSV file" - could you load it into another database table instead, then join the two tables in your query with an order by?

Comment: There is only 3 values to order so I guess I could just extract the ids based on each value (1-3) and `UNION` three separate selects, that is however not really scalable..

Comment: I'll look into your solution @Turophile !

Answer (score 1):

You can do the ordering in the database, with a single query by splitting the values into three groups:

```
select id, name
from item_data
order by (id in ($items_ids_csv_1)) desc,
         (id in ($items_ids_csv_2)) desc,
         (id in ($items_ids_csv_3)) desc;
```

This works because the expression `id in (...)` returns "1" when the `id` is in the list and "0" otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in a comment, if there are only 3 sequence values, split it into 3 parts:

```
# make 3 different $item_ids_csv
$item_ids_csv_1 = ...
$item_ids_csv_2 = ...
$item_ids_csv_3 = ...

...

$sql = "SELECT `id`,`name`,1 AS seq
        FROM `item_data`
        WHERE `id` IN ($item_ids_csv_1)
        UNION 
        SELECT `id`,`name`,2 AS seq
        FROM `item_data`
        WHERE `id` IN ($item_ids_csv_2)
        UNION 
        SELECT `id`,`name`,3 AS seq
        FROM `item_data`
        WHERE `id` IN ($item_ids_csv_3)
        ORDER BY seq, id;";
```